# TextView not showing up after activity switch

Tags: android

My main activity(one xml file, and one java file) contains a help button, and I want to display the whole layout(including the paragraph I typed on a Textview) after button clicked. It was successfully launched, all imageview were displayed but not the Textview.

Here's the content of the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tbs_background"
tools:context="limitless.the_bat_signal.aboutPage">

<TextView
    tools:text="about the app"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tbs_text_about"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbs_title_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

<TextView
    tools:text="@string/about"
    android:id="@+id/tbs_text_aboutDetails"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbs_text_about"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tbs_title_text"
    android:id="@+id/tbs_title_text"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbs_icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tbs_icon"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/tbs_icon"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tbs_home"
    android:background="@drawable/tbs_home"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tbs_title_text"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tbs_title_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>.
```

Then my Activity 2 named aboutPage calling out the XML file above:

```
public class aboutPage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_help;
TextView tbs_title_text;
TextView tbs_text_about_details;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

}
 }.
```

I'm new to android, please tell me what am I missing. Thanks!

Comment: First of all class name for convention are to be named capitalized => AboutPage. Please post main activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text` attribute in your code is wrong, the namespace should be `android:text="@string/about"` instead of `tools:text=="@string/about"`. 
So the resulting textview will look like,

```
<TextView
    android:text="about the app"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tbs_text_about"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbs_title_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Fix it and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using `tools:text` this is only for design view and will not translate to code. Use `android:text` instead.